# My kivy app properties updates but not my screen viwe

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a reroll button for my app.
The app is creating a random 5x5 grid and i want to change the grid each time i press reroll (while also changing grid size)
But when i press it my screen doesn't change at all. i can see in console logs that the properties are updated but i always have the same screen.
here is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import random


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.lignes=5
        self.colonnes=5
        self.agents=8
        self.assassins=1

        self.main_layout = self.affichage()
        return self.main_layout

    def affichage(self):
        main_layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")

        nb_cases=self.lignes*self.colonnes


        color_dic={
        'R':[1,0,0,1],
        'B':[1,0,1,1],
        'A':[1,0,0,1],
        '.':[1,1,1,1]
        }

        teams=['R','B']
        first_team=random.choice(teams)

        cases=[]
        cases.append(first_team)

        for i in range(self.agents):
            cases.append('R')
            cases.append('B')

        for i in range(self.assassins):
            cases.append('A')

        for i in range(len(cases),nb_cases):
            cases.append('.')

        plateau=[]

        while cases:
            case=random.choice(cases)
            plateau.append(case)
            cases.remove(case)


        top_layout = BoxLayout()
        button = Button(
            text='First team is ' + first_team,
            pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5},
            background_color=color_dic[first_team]
            )
        top_layout.add_widget(button)

        main_layout.add_widget(top_layout)

        info_layout = BoxLayout()
        button = Button(
            text='Plateau : '+str(self.lignes)+'x'+str(self.colonnes)+', Agents : '+str(self.agents)+', Assassins : '+str(self.assassins),
            pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5},
            background_color=[0,1,1,1]
            )
        info_layout.add_widget(button)

        main_layout.add_widget(info_layout)



        for i in range(self.lignes):
            h_layout = BoxLayout()
            for j in range(self.colonnes):
                case=plateau[i*self.colonnes+j]
                couleur=color_dic[case]
                button = Button(
                    text=case,
                    pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5},
                    background_color=couleur
                )
                h_layout.add_widget(button)
            main_layout.add_widget(h_layout)


        menu_layout = BoxLayout()
        button = Button(
            text='ReRoll',
            pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5},
            background_color=[0,1,0,1]
            )
        button.bind(on_press=self.reroll)
        menu_layout.add_widget(button)

        main_layout.add_widget(menu_layout)

        return main_layout



    def reroll(self,instance):
        self.lignes+=1
        self.colonnes+=1
        self.main_layout=self.affichage()
        print(self.lignes)
        print(self.main_layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call affichage function you create new object of box layout, but build method is called only once and it returns only first one object of box layout. So create one object and use it:

```
class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.lignes=5
        self.colonnes=5
        self.agents=8
        self.assassins=1
        self.main_layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        self.affichage()
        return self.main_layout

    def affichage(self):

        self.main_layout.clear_widgets()
        nb_cases=self.lignes*self.colonnes


        color_dic={
        'R':[1,0,0,1],
        'B':[1,0,1,1],
        'A':[1,0,0,1],
        '.':[1,1,1,1]
        }

        teams=['R','B']
        first_team=random.choice(teams)

        cases=[]
        cases.append(first_team)

        for i in range(self.agents):
            cases.append('R')
            cases.append('B')

        for i in range(self.assassins):
            cases.append('A')

        for i in range(len(cases),nb_cases):
            cases.append('.')

        plateau=[]

        while cases:
            case=random.choice(cases)
            plateau.append(case)
            cases.remove(case)

        top_layout = BoxLayout()
        button = Button(
            text='First team is ' + first_team,
            pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5},
            background_color=color_dic[first_team]
            )
        top_layout.add_widget(button)

        main_layout.add_widget(top_layout)

        info_layout = BoxLayout()
        button = Button(
            text='Plateau : '+str(self.lignes)+'x'+str(self.colonnes)+', Agents : '+str(self.agents)+', Assassins : '+str(self.assassins),
            pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5},
            background_color=[0,1,1,1]
            )
        info_layout.add_widget(button)

        main_layout.add_widget(info_layout)

        for i in range(self.lignes):
            h_layout = BoxLayout()
            for j in range(self.colonnes):
                case=plateau[i*self.colonnes+j]
                couleur=color_dic[case]
                button = Button(
                    text=case,
                    pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5},
                    background_color=couleur
                )
                h_layout.add_widget(button)
            main_layout.add_widget(h_layout)

        menu_layout = BoxLayout()
        button = Button(
            text='ReRoll',
            pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5},
            background_color=[0,1,0,1]
            )
        button.bind(on_press=self.reroll)
        menu_layout.add_widget(button)
        main_layout.add_widget(menu_layout)

    def reroll(self,instance):
        self.lignes+=1
        self.colonnes+=1
        self.affichage()
        print(self.lignes)
        print(self.main_layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

Comment: Thx a lot it worked and i understand what i did wrong.